# Hide and show window in python eel application

Tags: python, eel

I have a small application in eel that deploys some list of task. I want the window to be hidden after the user finishes the process and to be shown again when certain date time conditions are met. I want the window to be shown again with a different set of tasks that I read from an SQL database.

So I tried to deploy the app in mode "False" `(eel.start('xx.html, mode='False'))` and then use the `eel.show()` to launch the app at a certain date. But I can't manage to hide the window again without closing the python service.